# What's the most efficient way to get this data, thousands of times?

Tags: php, html, curl, html-parsing, scrape

What would be the best way to get the following data (the 4.0m after the `</b>` tag) using PHP's *DOMDocument->loadHTML()* system? I'm guessing some kind of CSS-stye selector?

`(LINE 240, always 240) <b>Current Price:</b> 4.0m`

I have been looking around the documentation, but to be honest this is all completely alien to me! Furthermore, how would I be able to get this data for thousands of pages, from URLs such as:

`http://site.com/q=item/viewitem.php?obj=11928`

The `obj=#` minimum/maximum values are known (how many pages I will need to scrape), and I want to grab all of them, incrementally, and output `name` `description` and `price` (not terribly concerned about the percentage rise/drop as of yet) to a MySQL database, so I can grab it from there and display it in my site.

Here is the main block of code that I am interested in:

```
<div class="subsectionHeader"> 
<h2> 
Item Name
</h2> 
</div> 
<div id="item_additional" class="inner_brown_box">  
Description of item goes here.
<br> 
<br> 
<b>Current Price:</b> 4.0m
<br><br> 
<b>Change in Price:</b><br> 
<span> 
<b>30 Days:</b> <span class="rise">+2.5%</span> 
</span> 
<span class="spaced_span"> 
<b>90 Days:</b> <span class="drop">-30.4%</span> 
</span> 
<span class="spaced-span"> 
<b>180 Days:</b> <span class="drop">-33.3%</span> 
</span> 
<br class="clear"> 
</div> </div> <div class="brown_box main_page"> 
<div class="subsectionHeader"> `
```

If anyone could provide any skeletal hints on how to go about this, it would be much appreciated!

Comment: Isn't there an RSS feed you can access? Scraping is near-universally considered to be bad form.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's the most efficient way to scrape -> store -> display this information?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5305436/whats-the-most-efficient-way-to-scrape-store-display-this-information)

Answer (score 1):

Parsing HTML with regular expressions is usualy bad idea, but in your case it may me right/easy way. It's fast enough and maybe more flexible than chunking with strpos and plain text patterns.

Try this example with source HTML given above:

```
//checked with php 5.3.3
if (preg_match('#<h2>(?P<itemName>[^>]+)</h2>.*?<div[^>]+id=([\'"])item_additional(\2)[^>]*>\s*(?P<description>[^<]+).*?<b>\s*Current\s+Price\s?:?</b>\s*(?P<price>[^<]+)#six',$src, $matches))
{
    print_r($matches);
}
```

Regular expressions might look too complex, but with documenation and nice tools like RegexBuddy or Expresso anyone can write simple ones ;)

Answer (score 0):

You could use Simple HTML DOM Parser - http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/

Extract the contents using:

```
echo file_get_html('http://www.google.com/')->plaintext;
```

And then locate the 4.0m using a PHP str function.

Answer (score 0):

DOM parsing is the most robust way to do this.

If you want the fastest way, and know that the HTML structure is consistent, it would *probably* be faster to use `strpos` to search for offsets. It is more likely to break if the page structure changes, though. Something like this:

```
$needles = array(
  'name' => "<div class=\"subsectionHeader\">\n<h2>\n"
  'description' => "<div id=\"item_additional\" class=\"inner_brown_box\">\n"
  'price' => "<b>Current Price:</b> "
);
$buffer = file_get_contents("http://site.com/q=item/viewitem.php?obj=1234");
$result = array();
foreach ($needles as $key => $needle) {
  $index1 = strpos($buffer, $needle);
  $index2 = strpos($buffer, "\n", $index1);
  $value = substr($buffer, $index1, $index2 - $index1);
  $result[$key] = $value;
}
```

You will need to get the needles exactly right, including any trailing whitespace.